# Accessing Inputs of a GUI using QT Designer (comboBox, spinBox, horizontalSlider)

Tags: python, user-interface

I tried to make this code as clear as possible. I got the bare-bones of the code using QT Designer

There are 3 main parts - accessing inputs (125-129), setting a command to the button (41-45), and defining the actions(155-168)(to simplify - print the inputs)

The problem with it as it stands, is that it doesn't output the correct value when using the GUI

For instance, when you change the horizontalSlider then press the button, it only prints "1", even though it should go up to "8"

I believe part of the problem has something to do with the "retranslateUi", but I cannot pinpoint it...

```
### I tried to make this code as clear as possible. I got the bare-bones of the code using QT Designer
### There are 3 main parts - accessing inputs (125-129), setting a command to the button (41-45), and defining the actions(155-168)(to simplify - print the inputs)
### The problem with it as it stands, is that it doesn't output the correct value when using the GUI 
### For instance, when you change the horizontalSlider then press the button, it only prints "1", even though it should go up to "8"
### I believe part of the problem has something to do with the "retranslateUi", but I cannot pinpoint it...

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets 
import sys


class Ui_StartWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, StartWindow):

        global lives, speed, letters1, letters2, letters3                   # need to makes these variables global in order to access them later on 

        StartWindow.setObjectName("StartWindow")
        StartWindow.resize(260, 260)
        StartWindow.setAutoFillBackground(False)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(StartWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        ### this is the horizontal slider (speed)
        self.horizontalSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalSlider.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 150, 181, 22))
        self.horizontalSlider.setMinimum(1)                                 # This is the minimum (the value is 1)
        self.horizontalSlider.setMaximum(8)                                 # This is the maximum (the value is 8)
        self.horizontalSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSlider.setObjectName("horizontalSlider")

        self.PushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.PushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 180, 161, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.PushButton.setFont(font)
        self.PushButton.setCheckable(False)
        self.PushButton.setObjectName("PushButton")

        self.PushButton.clicked.connect(action1)                          # this is what tells the push button to print the lives (3-5)
        self.PushButton.clicked.connect(action2)                          # this is what tells the push button to print the QWEletters ("Yes" or "No")
        self.PushButton.clicked.connect(action3)                          # this is what tells the push button to print the ASDletters ("Yes" or "No")
        self.PushButton.clicked.connect(action4)                          # this is what tells the push button to print the JKLletters ("Yes" or "No")
        self.PushButton.clicked.connect(action5)                          # this is what tells the push button to print the speed (1-8)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 120, 141, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 61, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 50, 61, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")

        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 80, 61, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")

        ### This is the comboBox (QWE)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 20, 41, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")

        ### This is the comboBox (ASD)
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 50, 41, 22))
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")

        ### This is the comboBox (JKL)
        self.comboBox_3 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 80, 41, 22))
        self.comboBox_3.setObjectName("comboBox_3")
        self.comboBox_3.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_3.addItem("")

        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 30, 91, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")

        ### This is the spinBox (lives)
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.spinBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 60, 71, 31))
        self.spinBox.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(61, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.spinBox.setFont(font)
        self.spinBox.setMinimum(3)                                          # this sets the minimum value for the lives (3)
        self.spinBox.setMaximum(5)                                          # this sets the maximum value for the lives (5)
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")

        ### Gets the inputs for the qwe, slider, and spinbox
        lives = int(self.spinBox.value())                                   # spinBox (lives)
        letters1 = self.comboBox.currentText()                              # comboBox (QWE)
        letters2 = self.comboBox_2.currentText()                            # comboBox (ASD)
        letters3 = self.comboBox_3.currentText()                            # comboBox (JKL)
        speed = self.horizontalSlider.sliderPosition()                      # horizontalSlider (speed)

        StartWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(StartWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        StartWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(StartWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(StartWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, StartWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        StartWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("StartWindow", "Start Window"))
        self.PushButton.setText(_translate("StartWindow", "Start!"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("StartWindow", "Speed (1-8) :"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("StartWindow", "QWE - "))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("StartWindow", " ASD - "))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("StartWindow", "  JKL - "))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("StartWindow", "Yes"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("StartWindow", "No"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(0, _translate("StartWindow", "Yes"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(1, _translate("StartWindow", "No"))
        self.comboBox_3.setItemText(0, _translate("StartWindow", "Yes"))
        self.comboBox_3.setItemText(1, _translate("StartWindow", "No"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("StartWindow", "# Lives :"))

def action1():                                                              # This is to access the lives -- spinBox
    print(lives)

def action2():                                                              # This is to access the letters (QWE) -- comboBox
    print(letters1)

def action3():                                                              # This is to access the letters (ASD) -- comboBox
    print(letters2)

def action4():                                                              # This is to access the letters (JKL) -- comboBox
    print(letters3)

def action5():                                                              # This is to access the speed -- horizontalSlider
    print(speed)


# if __name__ == "__main__":

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
StartWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_StartWindow()

ui.setupUi(StartWindow)
StartWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you can help in anyway, that would be fantastic. This has been an ongoing project, and I am trying to turn this into a learning experience. I have enjoyed it thus far, but I have a lot to learn.. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this what you were looking for. I'm still learning python currently, but I believe your functions were trying to access a class variable, but you weren't calling the variable correctly. Even though you set the variables to be global, they are global to the class scope. I moved the functions into the class, tweaked them a bit to capture the values of the comboBox, spinBox and horizontalSlider at the time of calling the functions.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys


class Ui_StartWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, StartWindow):

        # need to makes these variables global in order to access them later on
        global lives, speed, letters1, letters2, letters3

        StartWindow.setObjectName("StartWindow")
        StartWindow.resize(260, 260)
        StartWindow.setAutoFillBackground(False)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(StartWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        ### this is the horizontal slider (speed)
        self.horizontalSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalSlider.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 150, 181, 22))
        # This is the minimum (the value is 1)
        self.horizontalSlider.setMinimum(1)
        # This is the maximum (the value is 8)
        self.horizontalSlider.setMaximum(8)
        self.horizontalSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSlider.setObjectName("horizontalSlider")

        self.PushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.PushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 180, 161, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.PushButton.setFont(font)
        self.PushButton.setCheckable(False)
        self.PushButton.setObjectName("PushButton")

        # this is what tells the push button to print the lives (3-5)
        self.PushButton.clicked.connect(self.action1)
        # this is what tells the push button to print the QWEletters ("Yes" or "No")
        self.PushButton.clicked.connect(self.action2)
        # this is what tells the push button to print the ASDletters ("Yes" or "No")
        self.PushButton.clicked.connect(self.action3)
        # this is what tells the push button to print the JKLletters ("Yes" or "No")
        self.PushButton.clicked.connect(self.action4)
        # this is what tells the push button to print the speed (1-8)
        self.PushButton.clicked.connect(self.action5)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 120, 141, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 61, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 50, 61, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")

        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 80, 61, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")

        ### This is the comboBox (QWE)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 20, 41, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")

        ### This is the comboBox (ASD)
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 50, 41, 22))
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")

        ### This is the comboBox (JKL)
        self.comboBox_3 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 80, 41, 22))
        self.comboBox_3.setObjectName("comboBox_3")
        self.comboBox_3.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_3.addItem("")

        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 30, 91, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")

        ### This is the spinBox (lives)
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.spinBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 60, 71, 31))
        self.spinBox.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(61, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.spinBox.setFont(font)
        # this sets the minimum value for the lives (3)
        self.spinBox.setMinimum(3)
        # this sets the maximum value for the lives (5)
        self.spinBox.setMaximum(5)
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")

        ### Gets the inputs for the qwe, slider, and spinbox
        # spinBox (lives)
        # lives = int(self.spinBox.value())
        # letters1 = self.comboBox.currentText()                              # comboBox (QWE)
        # letters2 = self.comboBox_2.currentText()                            # comboBox (ASD)
        # letters3 = self.comboBox_3.currentText()                            # comboBox (JKL)
        # horizontalSlider (speed)
        # speed = self.horizontalSlider.sliderPosition()

        StartWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(StartWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        StartWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(StartWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(StartWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, StartWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        StartWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("StartWindow", "Start Window"))
        self.PushButton.setText(_translate("StartWindow", "Start!"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("StartWindow", "Speed (1-8) :"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("StartWindow", "QWE - "))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("StartWindow", " ASD - "))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("StartWindow", "  JKL - "))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("StartWindow", "Yes"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("StartWindow", "No"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(0, _translate("StartWindow", "Yes"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(1, _translate("StartWindow", "No"))
        self.comboBox_3.setItemText(0, _translate("StartWindow", "Yes"))
        self.comboBox_3.setItemText(1, _translate("StartWindow", "No"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("StartWindow", "# Lives :"))

    # This is to access the lives -- spinBox
    def action1(self):
        lives = int(self.spinBox.value())
        print(lives)

    # This is to access the letters (QWE) -- comboBox
    def action2(self):
        letters1 = self.comboBox.currentText()

        if letters1 == 'Yes':
            print('QWE')

    # This is to access the letters (ASD) -- comboBox
    def action3(self):
        letters2 = self.comboBox_2.currentText()

        if letters2 == 'Yes':
            print('ASD')

    # This is to access the letters (JKL) -- comboBox
    def action4(self):
        letters3 = self.comboBox_3.currentText()

        if letters3 == 'Yes':
            print('JKL')

    # This is to access the speed -- horizontalSlider
    def action5(self):
        speed = self.horizontalSlider.sliderPosition()
        print(speed)


# if __name__ == "__main__":

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
StartWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_StartWindow()

ui.setupUi(StartWindow)
StartWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```